# Optional regex group in Python failing

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do get some text between keywords into a text using regex. For example:

Text content:

```
Information Location
Porto Alegre
data data data data data data data data 
Geolocation
```

If I use this regex `(?:Information\sLocation\n.*\n)([\W\w]+)(?:Geolocation)`, I will get **data data data** .... It's fine! It's ok!

But, sometimes the text structure can be like this:

```
Information Location
Porto Alegre
data data data data data data data data
```

and my Regex fails! I've tried to find some way to put the last group (?:Geolocation) as optional , but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make the capture group less greedy with the addition of `?`
2. put an alternative of`\s*\Z` for end of file inside last group

Like so:

```
(?:Information\sLocation\n.*\n)([\W\w]+?)(?:Geolocation|\s*\Z)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPDg9F/1)

Comment: Btw: `(?:Information\sLocation\n.*\n)([^\n]+)\n?(?:Geolocation|\s*\Z)` works too and is significantly fewer steps. Assuming your data are all on 1 line.